# What's wrong with my urls.py?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying Django 1.11 and I have an issue :

This my file agora/agora/urls.py :

```html
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^start/', include('start.urls', namespace='start')),   
]
```

And this is my file agora/start/urls.py

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view_first, name='view_first'),    
    url(r'^/inscription', view_second, name='view_second'),
    url(r'^/about', view_about, name='view_about'),
]
```

The Django server return an error :

NameError: name 'view_first' is not defined

Many thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify the function name in the `import` statement

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import view_first, view_second, view_about

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view_first, name='view_first'),    
    url(r'^/inscription', view_second, name='view_second'),
    url(r'^/about', view_about, name='view_about'),
]
```

or import the view and assign each function with `view.`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view.view_first, name='view_first'),    
    url(r'^/inscription', view.view_second, name='view_second'),
    url(r'^/about', view.view_about, name='view_about'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for both solutions !

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this for all functions

```
views.view_first
views.view_second
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, the question has already been answered, I did happen to notice a minor but mistake.

When writing urls, adding "$" sign at the end of the endpoint is always recommended. Not adding the same may cause overlapping of similar urls which could confuse the app behaviour and even can cause some serious errors.
The dollar sign marks the end of the url string.

Just a heads up!!

Comment: Ok I will di it. Thank you very much !